# Access updating table with date using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table named `Functions` in MS Access and I would like the table to automatically update it self when a certain date reaches.

**TBL_functions**:

```
----------------------------------------------------
|tm_function | tm_start   | tm_end     | tm_archive |
 ---------------------------------------------------
|HV-1        | 09-03-2015 | 10-03-2015 |NO          |
|HV-2        | 09-03-2015 | 11-03-2015 |NO          |
|HV-3        | 09-03-2015 | 12-03-2015 |NO          |
|HV-4        | 09-03-2015 | 14-03-2015 |NO          |
```

So when the end date reaches today the row will change from archive no to yes

Maybe a on load VBA code that checks all dates when you open the form? Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Can you create a `SELECT` query which returns only those rows whose `tm_archive` values should be changed?

Comment: It makes no sense. How would _tm_end_ ever reach today's date - and, if so, why not at the same time set _tm_archive_ to YES? @HansUp and Darren?

Comment: @Gustav I was uncertain about the details on this one.  But pragmatically, if they can show us a `SELECT` which targets the rows which should be changed, it's easy to convert that to an `UPDATE`.

Comment: @Gustav - I'm assuming that the record is entered at some point in the past indicating the date that something needs archiving.  Then each time the database is opened it will check the dates that have been entered in the `tm_end` field and if we have reached the previously entered `tm_end` date then the record is updated.

Comment: Well, OK, but in that case all of the example rows would have been updated to YES. Except, of course, if this is an example of the past ...

Comment: @HansUp: That's true. But after all, you wouldn't need anything else but a select query with an expression like `tm_archive: tm_end<=Date()`

Comment: I asked for a `SELECT` which returns only those rows which must be changed.  I expected the `WHERE` clause would then include `tm_end<=Date()` and another condition to exclude those where `tm_archive` is already YES ... but uncertain about data type and whether Nulls permitted ... `tm_archive='NO' OR tm_archive Is Null` or `tm_archive = False`

Answer (score 3):

As HansUp suggested - have a query execute when the database opens.
This SQL will update the table where the date is equal or earlier to today.

```
UPDATE Functions
SET tm_archive = 'YES'
WHERE tm_end<=DATE()
```